# Chained routers

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I have an ISP-provided router that is connected to a broadband link.  I can browse the admin site of this router on IP 192.168.1.254.  In one of the ports on that router, I plugged in my own wireless router, which has the IP address 192.168.2.1.

A computer connected to the 192.168.1.254 router via CAT5 can browse Internet but cannot connect to the admin site of the 192.168.2.1 router.

If I connect a computer directly to one of the RJ45 ports on the 192.168.2.1 router, I can browse the admin site at 192.168.2.1.

- Is there a way I can configure the first router (192.168.1.254) to allow connected computers to see the second router (192.168.2.1)?
- Do I need to change the IP of the second router to be on the same network?

Comment: Is there a need for the 2nd subnet? I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use a larger subnet if you needed more IP addresses

Comment: What port of your own wireless router (@192.168.2.1) is connected to the ISP router?  (1) You should use a LAN port, not the WAN port.  Nothing should be connected to the WAN port of your wireless router. (2) Instead of 192.168.2.1, you should assign your own wireless router (its LAN side) an unused IP address in the 192.168.1.xxx range (and reserve that IP address on the ISP's router).  (3) And disable the DHCP server on your own wireless router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like router A (192.168.1.254) does not have a route to router B (192.168.2.1). Are you able to log into the administrative interface on Router A?

I am making an assumption that you are trying to make your wireless router, router B, serve as a wireless connection to the internet? If that's what you're doing then you'll want to log onto router B and change it to function as a Access Point instead of a Router. Change it's IP address to part of the 192.168.1.x subnet and most importantly you would want it to not be also serving DHCP.